# Problems connecting to my school's wifi

Tags: wireless, networking

So I have a lenovo yoga 2 pro with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, and so far I have had to blacklist ideapad_laptop to unblock my wifi adapter.

Now I'm having a hard time connecting to my school's secure wifi. I can see the access points but when I try to connect, the connection kind of dies. I have to restart the computer to get it back.

Here are the results of the wifi troubleshooting script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9903843/

Edit: Not sure what I did, but it connects now. The problem is that the connection is really crappy. Funny thing is, I only have these problems at school and in ubuntu. If I boot into windows 8.1 the internet works fine... I have been tethering my phone to get a more reliable connection.

Comment: That ca-cert you have applied. Is it supplied by the school?

Comment: As it's newer hardware, I would recommend trying ubuntu 14.10 and kernel 3.18. That fixed many problems like this for me, on my Sony Vaio Pro.

Comment: The ca-cert is the one that my school told me to use. I'm not sure I want to go through the trouble of upgrading if it isn't guaranteed to fix the problem.

Comment: I'd do it if you've exhausted your options. That fixed a handful of wireless and driver issues I've had with my laptop. Since those are usually fixed in newer kernels.

Comment: @davidbaumann Well, that seems to have fixed the problem. It's not even a crappy connection anymore. It also solved some UI problems I was having with chrome. Could you post your comment as an answer so  I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For very new hardware, you can try to install newer kernels.

For Ubuntu, they can be found here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.6-vivid/

For x64, you need 3 packages:

```
linux-headers-3.19.6-031906-generic
linux-headers-3.19.6-031906_3.19.6
linux-image-3.19.6-031906-generic_3.19.6
```

Download them to one folder, and install by:

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```